# JBoss EAP5 end of service

Tags: jboss5.x, jboss6.x

I am looking at the JBoss EAP5 end of service dates. Is it so that full support ended sometime  end of 2013, but partial support is still provided 3 years after that, including e.g. Critical patches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information are available on the Red Hat web:
https://access.redhat.com/site/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/#Life_cycle_dates

JBoss EAP 5:

- Maintenance Support end: Nov 2016
- Extended Life Support end: Nov 2019

The Extended Life support covers:

- Unlimited-incident technical support
- Asynchronous Security Patches
- Asynchronous Bug-Fix Patches